# manifest file is lost due to adding of common.gradle in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have two gradle . One is project level gradle and another is app level gradle . In app gradle when I add this line, "`apply from: "../../../buildCommon/common.gradle"`" , then manifest file is lost  .

The content of app level gradle is given here :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "../../../buildCommon/applicationCommon.gradle"
apply from: "../../../buildCommon/common.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "era.safetynet.payment.apps"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':ftrSDKHelperAndroid')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'

}
```

The content of `applicationCommon.gradle` is as follows :

```
// ============================================================================
// Main
// ============================================================================

project.ext.productRootDir = "E://Face Verification Application//Neurotec_Latest"
project.ext.productBinDir = new File(project.productRootDir, "Bin")
project.ext.productBinJavaDir = new File(project.productBinDir, "Java")
project.ext.productBinAndroidDir = new File(project.productBinDir, "Android")
project.ext.productLibAndroidDir = new File(project.productRootDir, "Lib/Android")

// ============================================================================
// Android
// ============================================================================

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        sourceSets {
            main {
                jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
                jniLibs.srcDir new File(projectDir, "lib")
            }
        }
    }
```

The content of `common.gradle` is as follows :

```
project.ext.defaultArchitectures = "arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,x86"

group = 'com.neurotec.samples'
version = '9.0.0.0'

// ============================================================================
// Android
// ============================================================================

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('src/main/tests')
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude "META-INF/LE-832C0.RSA"
        exclude "META-INF/LE-832C0.SF"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}

// ============================================================================
// Building
// ============================================================================

// Also delete all project related files from product bin directory.
clean {
    delete fileTree(dir: project.productBinAndroidDir , include: "${archivesBaseName}*.*")
}

// Copy data files images to project build directory so thay can be packed in apk.
if (project.hasProperty("ndfFiles")) {
    task prepareNdfFiles(type: Copy) {
        from "${project.productBinDir}/Data"
        includes = project.ndfFiles
        rename { String fileName ->
            fileName.replace('.ndf', '.ndf.jet')
        }
        into "${android.sourceSets.main.assets.srcDirs[0]}/data";
    }
    tasks.preBuild.dependsOn(prepareNdfFiles)
}

// Copy native libraries to project directory so thay can be packed in apk.
if (project.hasProperty("nativeLibsInclude") || project.hasProperty("nativeLibsExclude")) {
    if (!project.hasProperty("arch")) {
        project.ext.arch = project.defaultArchitectures;
    }
    int counter = 1;
    project.arch.split(',').each {
        String srcDir = "${project.productLibAndroidDir}/${it}"
        String dstDir = "${projectDir}/lib/${it}"
        task "prepareNativeLibs$counter"(type: Copy) {
            from srcDir
            if (project.hasProperty("nativeLibsInclude")) {
                for (String lib : project.nativeLibsInclude) {
                    include lib;
                }
            }
            if (project.hasProperty("nativeLibsExclude")) {
                for (String lib : project.nativeLibsExclude) {
                    exclude lib;
                }
            }
            into dstDir
        }
        tasks.preBuild.dependsOn("prepareNativeLibs$counter");
        counter++;
    }
}

// Copy apk to product bin directory.
task copyApk(type: Copy) {
    from "${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk"
    include "${project.archivesBaseName}-debug.apk"
    rename "${project.archivesBaseName}-debug.apk", "${project.archivesBaseName}.apk"
    into project.productBinAndroidDir
}
tasks.build.dependsOn(copyApk)

task deleteTemporaryFiles(type: Delete) {
    if (project.hasProperty("ndfFiles")) {
        for (String file : project.ndfFiles) {
            delete "${android.sourceSets.main.assets.srcDirs[0]}/data/${file}.jet";
        }
    }
    delete "${projectDir}/lib"
}
tasks.copyApk.dependsOn(deleteTemporaryFiles)

// ============================================================================
// Dependencies
// ============================================================================

dependencies {

    project.ext.modules = [
        "android":          "com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4",
        "acra":             "ch.acra:acra:4.5.0",
    ]

}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs "${project.productBinAndroidDir}/"
    }
}
```

Why is the manifest file lost ? Please help me as I am new in android studio .

I am also getting this error .

```
Error:Cannot read packageName from E:\Android App Source Code\agent banking\SafetyNetPayment\safetyNetPayment\AndroidManifest.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is manifest file is lost, It's path is not just defined correctly in the `common.gradle` file. If i'm not mistaken, your manifest file is in your `src\main` directory, so the `manifest.srcFile` should be defined as  `manifest.srcFile 'src\main\AndroidManifest.xml'`.